# SQLite JOIN if field1 = 0 else do not join and write field2

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

I have this tables:

```
-Customer-
ID | isUsingStandardNumber | name |...
1    1                       Cust1
2    0                       Cust2


-CustomerProducts-
number | customerNumber | customerID | ...
A123     cust2nr123       2

-Request-
ID | productNumber | customerID | ...
1    A123           1
2    A123           2
```

Now I try to display this table using select:

```
**SELECT Result**
RequestID | productNumber | customerNumber | customer
1           A123            A123             Cust1
2           A123            cust2nr123       Cust2
```

That means if customer is using own numbers, it should be an entry in "CustomerProducts". Otherwise the "customerNumber" column should have same entry as "productNumber". I tried this:

```
SELECT  Req.ID as 'Request Nr', 
  Prod.productNumber as 'Product Nr', 
   Case WHEN Cust.isUsingStandardNumber = 1
   THEN Prod.productNumber
   ELSE CustProd.customerNumber END as 'Customer Nr',
  Cust.name as 'Customer'
FROM Request Req
JOIN Customer Cust ON Cust.ID = Req.customerID
LEFT JOIN CustomerProducts CustProd ON CustProd.pn = Req.pn AND Req.customerID = CustProd.customerID
```

Now I only see results where the table CustomerProducts has entrys (only the second request) but not the first one.

Comment: Your design doesn't make much sense. Why would `customerNumber` be an attribute of `CustomerProducts`? That seems to be an field dependent on the `Customer` table.

Comment: customerNumber means the number the customer is using for the product, not the number of the customer